# Loading large raster dataset in to tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, convolutional-neural-network, image-preprocessing, geospatial

I am building a convolutional neural network for processing air quality concentration fields and meteorological parameter distribution. The input data are in Geotiff and NetCDF formats, which I load and convert into NumPy arrays with shapes (number of samples, dimX, dimY, channels). My training dataset contains over 12000 samples, each 237x400x8 channels. Loading this at one step makes the process very memory-demanding. Normally I would use an image generator, but as far as I am aware, it does not support .tiff files. I prefer not to convert to BMP (since this would destroy the spatial coordinates). So my question is - is there a standard way to deal with tif or netCDF data?

Comment: Is it for loading inputs for training/inference? It should be easy to write your own custom generator, so that only small batches or single files are loaded at a time. There seems to be many examples online both for Tensorflow and Keras.